# How to force header when creating hive .gz output

Tags: hadoop, hive, gzip

How do I make sure each .gz file is created with a header? I am setting these properties which give me multiple output files named 00000_0.gz, 00001_0.gz, 00002_0.gz, etc. But these have no header. What syntax do I need to force a header for each file?

BTW, my query is of the form

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/target_dir/' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' SELECT ...
```

Properties now set:

```
set mapred.output.compress=true; 
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;    
set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
```

Comment: What makes you think there is no header?

Comment: When I unzip and head the output file 00000_0.gz, there is no header

Comment: I thought you are talking about gzip header... :-) if you are talking  about columns names, so - no, it is not a supported feature.

Comment: so .. impossible?  If so, what about straight .csv without gzip?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The ugly non efficient work around it to set the headers on (`set hive.cli.print.header=true`), run the query using the CLI and spool the results.

Comment: Can you please expand on 'spool the results' ?

Comment: `hive --hiveconf hive.cli.print.header=true -e "select * from mytable" | tr '\t' '|' > myfile.txt`

Comment: Why don't you just write out the files un-compresssed, combine them into one, and then gzip that one file?

Comment: If you really, really want the headers, then you can use Spark to generate CSV files -- with optional headers, and optional compression. And map a Hive EXTERNAL table on the results -- with "skip 1 line of header" option.